# Get first element of a collection that matches iterator function

Tags: javascript, collections, functional-programming, underscore.js

I would like to achieve something like `_.first` with `_.filter`, that is, having a collection of elements, I'd like to get the first one (if exists) that matches a truth test (iterator).

For example, given an array like the following:

```
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 5}, {a: 9}, {a: 11}, {a: 15}]
```

I would like to getthe first (and only first) element that matches my custom function:

```
_.filterFirst(arr, function(el) { return el.a > 10; }); // make it
```

So far:

```
_.first(arr) == {a:1}
_.filter(arr, function(...)) == [{a:11}, {a:15}]
```

Is there a clean solution to do this which is better than `_.first(_.filter(arr, iterator))`?

Comment: Have a look at the find function http://underscorejs.org/#find

Comment: Why not just _.filter(arr, iterator)[0]

Comment: @levi because it consumes more CPU than it should.

Comment: Why not just _.filter(arr, iterator)[0]

Comment: @RobertRavikumar have you ever heard of performance? Or algorithmic complexity? [Here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/time-complexity-big-o-notation-1a4310c3ee4b) you go. BTW that question is 5-years old

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `find`:

> Looks through each value in the list, returning the first one that
>   passes a truth test (iterator), or undefined if no value passes the
>   test. The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element,
>   and doesn't traverse the entire list.

Using your example:

```
var g = _.find(arr, function (x) { return x.a > 10 })
```

See the main page: http://underscorejs.org

Another thing to note (which might be your question) is the `chain` function to join calls together:

```
var g = _.chain(arr).filter(function (x) { return x.a > 10 }).first().value()
```

Notice the calls to `filter` and `first' which can follow each other without any nesting.

Comment: precisely! `_.find` is what I need!

Comment: ...or Array.prototype.find(), but it's not supported by IE. One can use a polyfill though. Note that just translating ES2015+ to ES5 would not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the standard JavaScript [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, as just the old answers would leave newcomers ill informed:

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
const found = array1.find(element => element > 10);
console.log(found); 
// expected output: 12
```

The example is from the above linked MDN page.
There's also an [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method that returns the index of where the predicate yielded true, rather than the array element of that index.

These methods are in ES2015 ie. 5 years old and are in pretty much all of the browsers people use, see this [caniuse link](https://caniuse.com/array-find-index).

Answer (score 0):

"_.find" is a good solution.

An alternative solution, maybe faster, is to use "Array.prototype.every" in this way:

```
var match;
arr.every(function(x) { if (x.a > 10) { match = x; return false;} return true; })
```

Answer (score 0):

_.find - in lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#find

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// => object for 'barney'

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => object for 'pebbles'

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, ['active', false]);
// => object for 'fred'

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, 'active');
// => object for 'barney'
```